Type narrowing via inequality check against single-member enum works only for unions with certain types
Consider:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from uuid import UUID
from enum import Enum

class E(Enum):
    m = "m"

@dataclass
class A:
    e: str | E

a = A(E.m)

def f(x: str) -> None:
    print(x)

if a.e != E.m:
    f(a.e)

Running Mypy against this in --strict mode reports no errors, because it correctly infers that the type of a.e can only be str if it isn't E.m. But changing that str to e.g. a UUID, i.e.
@dataclass
class A:
    e: UUID | E

def f(x: UUID) -> None:
    print(x)

causes Mypy to report:
bug.py:18: error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "UUID | E"; expected "UUID"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Is there a logical reason why it's allowed to infer the type of a.e as stated in one case but not the other or is this a bug in Mypy?

This is because UUID overloads __eq__. From typeshed/stdlib/uuid.py:
class UUID:
    # ...
    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool: ...

Using is not solves the problem:
(playground)
if a.e is not E.m:
    f(a.e)  # fine

